# How to instruct AEM to look for a specific resource bundle translations

Tags: internationalization, aem, resourcebundle

I have two websites and code base is same.

SiteA
SiteB

apps/company/components

How to pick different resource bundle translations for SiteA, SiteB in i18n ?

Thanks,
Sri

Comment: afaik, its not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Can you please be specific, is this for server side translations or client side translations? For client-side translations, I had an issue with OTB ResourceBundleExportServlet detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45330214/can-i-get-entire-i18n-labels-of-specific-dictionary/46224288#46224288).

[sling:basename](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/internationalization-support-i18n.html#resourcebundle-with-base-names) way:

1. Add a property sling:basename to mix:language node. Say sling:basename="siteA"
2. Pass the basename during bundle lookup. request.getResourceBundle("siteA", locale);
3. This will return keys from the specific basename only.

Client-side custom bundle exporter:

1. Keep separate dictionaries for SiteA and SiteB. For example: /apps/company/sitea/i18n, /apps/company/siteb/i18n.
2. If splitting dictionary is not possible, keep a nomenclature in your labels to identify site. For example all labels should be prefixed with siteA/siteA. Like siteA.clickhere, siteB.clickhere
3. Create custom servlet similar to ResourceBundleExportServlet. Keep the path as /libs/company/i18n/dict.
4. The custom servlet will check siteA or siteB from slingrequest and return respective labels only. Filtering the labels based of dictionary path(step 1) or prefix(step 2)
5. Create overlay to /libs/clientlibs/granite/utils/source/I18n.js. Change the urlPrefix to

   var urlPrefix = "/libs/company/i18n/dict.";
6. Now the client side i18n lookup will pull entries from the custom exporter rather than OTB exporter

Server-side Resolver:

1. To differentiate sitea or siteb labels we need step 1 or 2 from above.
2. Once we know to identify site specific labels, we need only a helper util that checks site from request and resolves from specific dictionary or prefix

Hope this helps.