# Load Site Specific Dictionary

Tags: aem

We have dictionary under /content/dam for languages say (en-us, es-us) . When we load the page its injected and we have the translated content render on the page. As part of the requirement I have some doubts to clarify.

1. When I load the page, I see multiple calls of /libs/cq/i18n/dict.xxx.json, how can we restrict default dictionary calls?

```
        /libs/cq/i18n/dict.en.json
    
        /libs/cq/i18n/dict.en-US.json (We need only this one)
    
        /libs/cq/i18n/dict.en.json
```

2. My custom dictionary `/libs/cq/i18n/dict.en-US.json` has only 5 labels, but in response i see via `<%= slingRequest.getResourceBundle(slingRequest.getLocale()).keySet()%><br>`  , numbers of other labels may be injected via `/libs/cq/i18n/dict.en.json`
3. Is there way to load `/libs/cq/i18n/dict.en-US.json` as per site level. Say, I want to load the dictionary on /content/mySiteA/en-US and not on /content/mySiteB/en-US ? keeping in consideration that codebase is same.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55622583/how-to-instruct-aem-to-look-for-a-specific-resource-bundle-translations

Comment: Did you try the above solution or did you find any other workaround?